# How can the server communicate to a specific client in a Client-Server system?

Tags: java, client-server, communication

By writing simple *System.out.println()* on server side, the message goes to all clients. 
But is there a way to make one client's address embedded to a java function 
which recognize that the server is sending a message to this specific client?

Comment: System.out.println() prints on server console not the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably requires a bit more information to be specific, but I'll try and run with it.

So if you have a server that maintains a list of clients that are connected, you could ideally tag each one with some type of ID when they make a connection into the server.

For example lets say you had a server that managed some kind of data and two types of clients could connect: Managers and Customers.

Now when a client connects you can setup the server so that it asks the user which they are and verify with a login maybe. Continuing from that you could place all of the types into unique lists and then broadcast to those lists separately.

Additionally since you can control the server and client application. You could generate a random ID number/tag/something for each user that connects and store that in a list. Then should the server want to message a unique client you just have to search the list(or hashmap) for that users socket/connection and broadcast to them.

I know this answer seems a bit vague but the information provided felt that way.

Comment: Thank you. That's really the hint I needed. All my clients have an ID. So, for an example, if a send a message to the client number "1" inside of a loop where i=1, (i varies from 0 to number_of_clients), WILL I send the message to client 1 or to all clients?

Comment: So if you believe that you will be constantly using the server to send messages to a single client, I would consider organizing the clients by indexing them into a data structure based on their tags. Specifically to your mention of a for-loop, as long as you add the conditional of an if(clientToMessage == clientID) for sending you should be fine, I would also throw a break to kill the for loop once you find your client.

My mention of a data structure would allow you to search for the client object and specifically call a SEND message on it, given you have it setup that way. Just my thoughts.